# Use arara with continuous compilation (with vimtex)

Tags: compiling, vim, arara

I've been using `vimtex` with `latexmk` to typeset my LaTeX documents for a while now.
But I'm trying to use `arara` for a new project, as one of the team members suggested to use it.

Since I always use `(Neo)vim` with `vimtex` to typeset documents, I looked up on a documentation and voila!
`vimtex` does support `arara`.
I added

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'arara'
```

and saw that `\ll` works to compile the document.
However I noticed it won't automatically compile the documents when I save the file using `:w`, and won't even clean the project files with `\lc`.

I then found this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/907) and found out the fact that I need to manually add something like:

```
% arara: clean: { files: [ mypaper.log ] }
```

to my tex file.
I'm fine with that–but I found it cumbersome to hit `\ll` everytime I `:w` to save the file to recompile.
I skimmed the `vimtex` manual to find out:

> arara does not do continuous compilation, and so the only relevant commands
>   are VimtexCompile to start (single shot) compilation, and
>   VimtexCompileOutput to see the compilation output.

So the question is, is there a work around using `(Neo)vim` or `vimtex` or `arara` perhaps borrow the help of `latexmk` to automatically compile my documents when they get saved?
One of the reasons I sticked with my setup (`vim` + `vimtex` + `skim`) was the automatic compilation, and it would be awesome if I can achieve something similar when using `arara` as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim provides *events* for which you can define `autocmd`s to execute whatever you want when an event occurs. [`:h autocmd-events`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events)

I would thus suggest you put the following in `ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
autocmd! BufWritePost *.tex normal ,ll
```

After this line is evaluated, everytime you write with `:w` on a file which ends with `.tex`, vim will execute `,ll` as if you were in normal mode

Note that this is only a vim feature and has nothing to do with arara.

Comment: Why haven't I thought of this! Thanks.